# Converting rpart model into PMML (using 'pmml' package)

Tags: r, rpart, pmml

I get the following error when I try to convert my `rpart` model into a `pmml`:

```
Fehler in if (ff$nsurrogate[parent_ii] > 0) { :   
    Fehlender Wert, wo TRUE/FALSE nötig ist
    (Missing value where TRUE / FALSE is needed)
```

This error can be reproduced by the code bellow:

```
library(rpart)
library(pmml)
df <- structure(list(a = structure(c(15L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 11L, 25L, 6L, 
                                     24L, 27L, 9L, 2L, 18L, 28L, 14L, 5L, 17L, 20L, 21L, 16L, 7L, 
                                     22L, 19L, 23L, 26L, 3L, 10L, 12L, 4L), .Label = c("013", "018", 
                                                                                       "063", "073", "122", "173", "212", "216", "296", "355", "410", 
                                                                                       "415", "423", "428", "453", "481", "534", "586", "678", "701", 
                                                                                       "735", "746", "778", "812", "818", "855", "864", "998"), class = "factor"), 
                     y = c(1.029993, 0.95987, 0.95987, 0.95987, 0.95987, 0.95987, 
                           0.95987, 0.969903, 0.95987, 0.860644, 0.95987, 0.969903, 
                           0.900669, 0.95987, 0.95987, 0.95987, 1.12018, 0.95987, 0.95987, 
                           0.95987, 0.95987, 0.880656, 0.95987, 0.939858, 0.95987, 0.939858, 
                           0.95987, 0.95987)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")

model <- rpart(y ~ a, df, control = rpart.control(minsplit = 1, minbucket = 2, cp=-1))
pmml.rpart(model)
```

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
>   Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
>
> Matrix products: default
>   BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
>
> locale:
>    [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
>    [6] LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
>   [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] pmml_1.5.7    XML_3.98-1.16 rpart_4.1-13
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] compiler_3.5.1 magrittr_1.5   tools_3.5.1    yaml_2.2.0     stringi_1.2.4  stringr_1.3.1

Comment: So, did our answers help?

Comment: The requirement was to grow a full tree with no pruning. That’s why we used “cp=-1”. But this was the problem to create the pmml. “cp=0” has the same effect on the tree and “pmml.rpart” worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `df$a` is a factor, which doesn't really make sense given that the number of rows equals the number of factor levels. Fixing that with

```
df$a <- as.numeric(as.character(df$a))
```

also allows to run

```
pmml.rpart(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `r2pmml` package instead: https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml

The conversion succeeds with the above code as-is, and the generated PMML model file is smaller, cleaner and provably correct:

```
library("r2pmml")
r2pmml(model, "model.pmml")
```